# "The directory name is invalid." does anybody have any ideas on how to go about fixing this command prompt error?

Tags: cmd, command

Hi can anyone help me out ?

I have just gotten a new laptop for developing and i have come to a halt already(7 mins).

When accessing files via the command prompt i keep getting this error "The directory name is invalid."

My file is saved on the desktop , i can navigate there well and good its just i cant enter into my eggs file or any file on my desktop via the command prompt. The path is correct.

`C:\Users\toshiba\Desktop> cd ChromeSetup.exe`

> The directory name is invalid.

I have messed around with the command prompt settings and that but to no avail :/. If someone could help me out id be so grateful as i have to start an important project and have been stuck on this for a while now. Thanks in advance.

Comment: i also cant access files in documents/ downloads etc

Comment: You are going to have to provide more clues. Please copy and paste from the cmd shell your command and the output into the question.

Comment: Are you sure that "ChromeSetup.exe" is a directory? It looks like the name of a file. If you double-check what is listed by the `dir` command against the directory you're trying to access, that might help.

Answer (score 4):

You can CD to **folders**, not to **files**.

This is because CD is short for:

> Change Directory

`cd ..\..\toshiba\Desktop` should work, because you CD in your folders

running `cd ChromeSetup.exe` is **never** going to work, unless ChromeSetup.exe is some weird folder name.

---

If you want to execute that executable without closing the CMD prompt, run this command:

```
cmd /K "ChromeSetup.exe"
```

---

If you want to open a file with a chosen program, use the executable command and give the filename as parameter:

```
"C:\Program Files\Adobe\Photoshop\photoshop" "C:\Users\user\Documents\document.pdf"
```

Comment: thanks man but it is not working for my tom.pem file or any other file for that matter :/

Comment: this opens the file but i just have to navigate to its level " dektop/ file.html" for example. I have to run a chmod command to make it private but i cant get to it ;/

Comment: @BeannaeB You don't want to CD to the file, you want to cd to the folder containing the file. If you are in the Desktop folder, you cannot come any closer to the `file.html` file. Please keep in mind that `chmod` is Linux and you are working on a Windows machine..

Comment: @BeannaeB You can open the explorer in the current directory using `explorer.exe .` command (Note the period after the space), right click the file and set the security you want to, like read-only.